Branch.io OG Tags Not Displaying on LinkedIn but Work on Facebook and Slack
Problem Description:
I'm encountering an issue with Open Graph (OG) tags not displaying correctly when sharing Branch.io links on LinkedIn. The same links work as expected on Facebook and Slack, showing the appropriate image, title, and description in previews. However, on LinkedIn, the preview shows a generic image instead of the correct OG metadata.
Link Details:
Here’s a sample link for testing:

Link: https://heroicminds.test-app.link/episode/test

This link renders correctly on Facebook and Slack, showing the correct image and title.
Steps Taken:

Used LinkedIn’s Post Inspector to test the link.
The image and title fail to load properly on LinkedIn, showing a broken or generic preview image.
Validated OG tags on the webpage source code, which seems to be correctly implemented:

$og_image_url
$og:title



Request Body for Updating the Link:
Attached is the request body we are using to update the link.

Issue on LinkedIn:
Here’s what LinkedIn shows:

What I've Tried:

Cleared the LinkedIn cache using their Post Inspector tool.
Ensured that OG tags are correctly implemented in the Branch.io deep link.

Expected Behavior:

The shared Branch.io link should display the correct OG image, title, and description on LinkedIn, just like on Facebook and Slack.

Question:
What could be causing LinkedIn to fail in recognizing OG tags from a Branch.io link while it works perfectly on other platforms? Are there any known limitations with LinkedIn and Branch.io, or additional steps required to fix this issue?

It looks like customizing the image is now only available for Enterprise plans. I was having the same issue and they mentioned this changed about a month ago.
From Branch Support:
This was changed after some privacy concerns were discovered.
At this time, only customers on an Enterprise plan have access to edit the link image preview. This was quite a surprise to us on the sales team, and I understand that it may be disappointing and frustrating.
Most customers upgrade to Enterprise once their app has 100-150K+ MAUs and/or they're ready to make a significant investment in deep linking and attribution (i.e., Enterprise plans start at $36K per year).
Again, happy to connect and chat further - please share any thoughts or questions in the meantime.
Best,

New links dont work for any social preview not just linkedin.
